# response.body().getBasketShopList is empty, but API JSON in Postman is not empty

Tags: java, android, retrofit, postman

I am new to Android, it's about a week that I am spending 3 hours a day on this problem but still I can not find a solution, I am going to get a list of object from server and pass them to Adapter and another process. But I got into trouble, there is no error, in my Android Studio I got " response.code = 200 " but a list of my object is empty although in Postman with same authorization and same username a list of object is not empty. I don't know what should I do, so finally I forced to ask my question hear.

First let's take a look on Postman

Body : :
[image: Body :]

Authorization : :
[image: Authorization :]

Now when I clicked on Send Button in Postman I got "code: 200" and hear is the response Body:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "_id": "5c7e69d283c0b00001108fad",
            "count": 2,
            "productId": "5ba51d877246b700016ec205",
            "username": "rezash",
            "createdAt": "2019-03-05T12:21:38.196UTC",
            "updatedAt": "2019-03-05T12:36:11.058UTC",
            "ACL": {
                "*": {
                    "read": true,
                    "write": true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "5c7e69d483c0b00001108fae",
            "count": 4,
            "productId": "5acc0f2c790c0c000132c984",
            "username": "rezash",
            "createdAt": "2019-03-05T12:21:40.338UTC",
            "updatedAt": "2019-03-05T12:36:15.830UTC",
            "ACL": {
                "*": {
                    "read": true,
                    "write": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In my OnlineShopAPI Interface:

```
public interface OnlineShopAPI {

    String BASE_URL = "https://api.backtory.com/";

    @Headers("X-Backtory-Object-Storage-Id:5a154d2fe4b03ffa0436a535")
    @HTTP(method = "POST" , path = "object-storage/classes/query/Basket" , hasBody = true)
    Call<MainBasketShopResponse> mainBasketShop (
            @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
            @Body BasketShop basketShop
    );

    interface getMainBasketShop {

        void onResponse(List<BasketShop> basketShopList);

        void onFailure(String cause);
    }
}
```

My MainBasketShopResponse class:

```
public class MainBasketShopResponse {

    @SerializedName("results")
    List<BasketShop> basketShopList;

    public MainBasketShopResponse() {
    }


    public List<BasketShop> getBasketShopList() {
        return basketShopList;
    }

    public void setBasketShopList(List<BasketShop> basketShopList) {
        this.basketShopList = basketShopList;
    }
}
```

BasketShop class:

```
public class BasketShop {

    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;

    @SerializedName("productId")
    private String productId;

    @SerializedName("count")
    private float count;


    @SerializedName("createdAt")
    private String createdAt;


    @SerializedName("_id")
    private String id;

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public BasketShop(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public BasketShop() {
    }

    public BasketShop(String username, String productId, float count) {
        this.username = username;
        this.productId = productId;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public BasketShop(String createdAt, String id) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public float getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(float count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

}
```

My Controller that contain retrofit:

```
public class MainBasketShopController {

    OnlineShopAPI.getMainBasketShop getMainBasketShop;

    public MainBasketShopController(OnlineShopAPI.getMainBasketShop getMainBasketShop) {
        this.getMainBasketShop = getMainBasketShop;
    }

    public void start(String authorization , BasketShop basketShop){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(OnlineShopAPI.BASE_URL)
                .build();

        OnlineShopAPI onlineShopAPI = retrofit.create(OnlineShopAPI.class);
        Call<MainBasketShopResponse> call = onlineShopAPI.mainBasketShop(authorization , basketShop);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<MainBasketShopResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MainBasketShopResponse> call, Response<MainBasketShopResponse> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {


                    Log.d("emptyhst1" , response.body().getBasketShopList().toString());
                    Log.d("emptyhst2" , Integer.toString(response.body().getBasketShopList().size()));
                    getMainBasketShop.onResponse(response.body().getBasketShopList());

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MainBasketShopResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                getMainBasketShop.onFailure(t.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hear is a part of my BasketShopFragment that I call MainBasketShopController with it:

```
MainBasketShopController mainBasketShopController = new MainBasketShopController(getMainBasketShop);
    BasketShop basketShop = new BasketShop();
    basketShop.setUsername(MyPreferenceManager.getInstance(getContext()).getUsername());
    mainBasketShopController.start(
            "bearer " + MyPreferenceManager.getInstance(getContext()).getAccessToken() ,
            basketShop
    );

OnlineShopAPI.getMainBasketShop getMainBasketShop = new OnlineShopAPI.getMainBasketShop() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(List<BasketShop> basketShopList) {

        Log.d("emptyhst3" , basketShopList.toString());

        basketShopList2.clear();
        basketShopList2.addAll(basketShopList);
        mainBasketShopAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(String cause) {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), cause , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
};
```

I  checked both of username and accessToken that i passed to the controller and I am sure that everything is looking like in Postman

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: Also, you can pre- and postfix code blocks with three backticks ( `\``) rather than just indenting the first line. Alternatively you can highlight all the code and press CTRL+K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week I found a solution , I just changed a variable "float count" to "String count" from my Model(BasketShop Class) Ops!

```
@SerializedName("count")
private String count;
```