# Gson don't use default field value for objects (not primitives)

Tags: java, android, gson

I use gson in android project and got problem. I want to set default value for list object if Api give me null value for this field. I don't modify this field any more so i don't want to check it every time for null value

So if be more detailed

I have for example this class

```
class Model {
    @Expose private int test = 1;
    @Expose private int primitive = 1;
    @Expose private List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and json from Api

```
{
"test" : 12
}
```

so i expect what gson will generate object with fields:

```
Model obj = gson.fromJson(json, Model.class);
// obj.test == 12;
// obj.primitive = 1;
// obj.strings = [] empty string array
```

but gson override non primitive fields

```
Model obj = gson.fromJson(json, Model.class);
// obj.test == 12;
// obj.primitive = 1; // int is primitive and gson use default value
// obj.strings = null // here error
```

I checked source code and found what ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.BoundField use default value only for primitives.

```
@Override void read(JsonReader reader, Object value) throws IOException, IllegalAccessException {
    Object fieldValue = typeAdapter.read(reader);
    if (fieldValue != null || !isPrimitive) {
        field.set(value, fieldValue);
    }
}
```

so i'm asking if somebody know how fix this problem, and make gson return non null values for non primitives fields

Comment: You can create custom deserializer for that purpose

Comment: prolem what i already have deserializer for the model class, because json have dynamic properties

Comment: I checked your example and it works as expected. Which version of `Gson` do you use?

Comment: i think that your problem is as same as my problem , sometimes you got 200 status code from calling API but your model is empty , cause you defined bad model , check hear : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55008519/response-body-getbasketshoplist-is-empty-but-api-json-in-postman-is-not-empty/55023531#55023531

Comment: @MichałZiober i use com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5

Comment: @rezashah unfortunately no, i tested this by creation java object from empty json object "{}", and all primitive field was initialized, but object not

Comment: Could you please create new class as I posted in answer and run this simple test? Maybe other layers of your app changes it?

Answer (score 0):

I created simple test which shows that `Gson` sets `List<String>` property to `null` only when is set to `null` in `JSON` payload. Below test app:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        System.out.println(gson.fromJson("{}", Model.class));
        System.out.println(gson.fromJson("{\"strings\":[]}", Model.class));
        System.out.println(gson.fromJson("{\"strings\":[1,2]}", Model.class));
        System.out.println(gson.fromJson("{\"strings\":null}", Model.class));
        System.out.println(gson.fromJson("{\"test\":12}", Model.class));
    }
}

class Model {

    @Expose
    private int test = 1;

    @Expose
    private int primitive = 1;

    @Expose
    private List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Model{" +
                "test=" + test +
                ", primitive=" + primitive +
                ", strings=" + strings +
                '}';
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Model{test=1, primitive=1, strings=[]}
Model{test=1, primitive=1, strings=[]}
Model{test=1, primitive=1, strings=[1, 2]}
Model{test=1, primitive=1, strings=null}
Model{test=12, primitive=1, strings=[]}
```

See also:

- [Gson uses TypeAdapter or Json Deserializer to convert data from an error list to an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55085592/gson-uses-typeadapter-or-json-deserializer-to-convert-data-from-an-error-list-to)